# С какой литературы лучше всего стоит начать изучать Hibernate и Spring для Java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc

С какой литературы лучше всего стоит начать изучать Hibernate и Spring для Java? Желательно на русском если есть.

Answer (score 2):

С официальной документации на английском. Особенно хорош reference для Spring.